# If holomorphic $\{f_n\}\to f$ uniformly on compact subsets of $U$, then do $f_n$ and $f$ eventually have the same number of zeros?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$. Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of holomorphic functions on $U$ such that $f_n\to f$ uniformly on any compact subset $K$ in $U$. Suppose $f$ is not constant, then zeros of $f$ are isolated. By Rouche theorem, I obtained that:

for any compact $K$ in $U$, there exists compact $K_1$ with $K\subseteq K_1\subset U$ and integer $M$ such that for any $n\geq M$, $N(f_n,K_1)=N(f,K_1)$. Here $N$ denotes number of zeros of a function in a region.

Is it true that: there exists integer $M$ such that for any $n\geq M$, $N(f_n,U)=N(f,U)$?

Comment: Take $U=\mathbb{C}$, $f_n(z)=1+z/n$, $f(z)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Think of Blaschke products: they are infinite, they may consist of an infinite number of zeros, although any partial product contains only $n$.

So yes, once you trace a curve (of nonzero index) where $f$ does not vanish you will have that the number of zeros in its interior is eventually constant, but that does not extrapolate to the general case.

Take for instance the function  $\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)}$, which can be expressed as an infinite product with all negative integers as simple zeros.

See formula (G50), page 9 of the following.
http://www.utdallas.edu/eecs/booksite/pdf/appG.pdf